# Node Modules Not Found, Using Ubuntu 20.04.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I an a Windows 10 user who uses WSL. I was using Ubuntu 20.04.5 provided from the Microsoft Store and executing node commands with no issues. However, I attempted to update Ubuntu 20.04.5 to Ubuntu Jammy (22.x) and I found that it was generating some errors when I attempted to utilize nodejs after installing nodejs and npm.
I decided to go back to using Ubuntu 20.04.5, and after reinstalling nodejs and npm I am encountering the same issues I had on Jammy. When I try to run my plain JavaScript app using node, I am greeted with the following error.
So far, I have found nothing that has solved my problem.

I also tried restarting the terminal as well as my computer. I am continually met with an error indicating that it cannot find the modules I am looking for. Please note that I have not used yarn or curl for any downloads, and have only used apt install as well as npm install.

When I attempt to run my app.js file in the correct directory.

```
>> node app.js
noseinternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'stream/promises'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/.../group-project-1-group-6-15064/lib/weatherHandler.js:4:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

So far, the error seems to make sense. Even though I have a node_modules folder in the directory, it may not have the specific module it is trying to load.

So I then try to use the node install command to install all dependencies based on my package.json.

```
>> node install
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/c/Users/.../group-project-1-group-6-15064/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

This command worked perfectly before I reinstalled everything.

I also tried to add to the PATH in my .bashrc file to no avail. I'm sure it's something so simple and frustrating, but after over 30 hours of troubleshooting, I have yet to have any kind of breakthrough.

Possibly useful info:

```
>> which node
/usr/bin/node

>> node -v
V10.19.0

>> which npm
/usr/bin/npm

>> npm -v
6.14.4

>> sudo npm install --global --verbose nodejs
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--global',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'nodejs' ]
npm info using npm@6.14.4
npm info using node@v10.19.0
...
npm verb unbuild rmStuff nodejs@0.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
...
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`stream/promises` was added in Node 15: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-promises-api.

You have to update your Node.js, for that please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

You may use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install and manage Node versions

```
# Download curl CLI utility
sudo apt-get install curl

# download nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

command -v nvm
```

If that doesn't work refer to [nvm's troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux).

Once you setup `nvm`, you can run

```
nvm install 16 # For example to install Node.js v16
nvm use 16 # To enable it in your current terminal
```

After that, you may need to reinstall your packages to avoid any unwanted behavior, just delete `node_modules` in your current project and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: I was trying to do this by avoiding the use of nvm and curl, because I didn't want to install any additional software. I decided to use curl once I realized that it was already installed on my machine. I also realize that I mixed up my npm install command with node install, which is not a valid command. Thank you! 
Prior, I thought that I had updated node to v16 by using npm install 16.0.0, but the command did not work for me this time around. Any idea what happened there?

Comment: To install node 16 you have to run `nvm install 16`, not `npm`, you want to use the *node versions manager* instead of *node package manager*. In the first installation of Node.js you might used a parameter to install node v10 instead of the latest one, or you missed running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` before downloading Node